# Windows Change Specific Console Color While Program is Running

Tags: windows, command-line, shell, colors, console

Is there a command I can run to change a single color in the command line to a different one, during runtime? For example, I can change a color by right clicking on cmd.exe, going into the color tab under Properties, and change a color there, but this will make it permanent. If I want to change it while a program is running, how would I do that?

For example, suppose I want to change the dark yellow color below to orange once a certain condition is met. How would I do that?

[image]

A batch file or powershell script would be fine as an example.

Comment: Use the `color` command. Type `color /?` in a blank cmd window to get more info about the sytax of that command.  There are 16 colors for you to chose from, and is fairly simple. (You can change both Font Color and Foreground color through this command. 

Eg: Syntax for green font color : `color 2` 
This changes the font color to green. 

Eg: Syntax to set foreground color to green : `color 72` 
This sets the font color to white and foreground to green.

This can be used in a batch file as well with the same syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the
[color command](https://ss64.com/nt/color.html).

Syntax :

```
  COLOR [background][foreground]
```

Colour attributes are specified by 2 of the following hex digits.
There should be no space between the two color numbers.

Each digit can be any of the following values:

```
0 = Black
8 = Gray

1 = Blue
9 = Light Blue

2 = Green
A = Light Green

3 = Aqua
B = Light Aqua

4 = Red
C = Light Red

5 = Purple
D = Light Purple

6 = Yellow
E = Light Yellow

7 = White
F = Bright White
```

For example, for setting the screen to black-on-yellow, use :

```
color 60
```

The changes are local to the current CMD session.

---

If you wish to do local changes to the text colors, you should use
[ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

For more information, see :

- [How-to: Use ANSI colors in the terminal](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-ansi.html)
- [ANSI Escape Sequences](https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797)

Comment: This doesn't have the same effect as changing the color from the properties section. This changes the color of all the text, not certain text. For example, what if I want to only change the dark yellow color but leave the white text alone?

Comment: You may change both the background/screen and the foreground/text colors. What else is there?

Comment: programs can output text in different colors; I could simultaneously have both white and yellow text appearing in the console window. I'm only wanting to change the color the yellow text, not all the text.

Comment: I added more info about ANSI Escape Sequences, if that's what you're referring to.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1761568/1737567 < I think my answer below, will solve your question. Check  if it works : )

Answer (score 0):

Its easy!

As you can see in this batch file code here:

```
@echo off

Powershell -command "Write-Host 'I'm Printed in RED!' -ForegroundColor Red"

@pause
```

> The `write-host` command prints out a text, and the `ForegroundColor`
> command sets the Text color to (in this case) red. The best part is,
> you can change a specific scentence/word or even a Letter to another
> color!

You can even add this powershell code into a CMD, or a batch file, and it works.

*EDIT: If you want to Change color when a condition is met, then you can do this :*

```
@echo off
 
::Your condition here
::Eg: if %errorlevel%==1 (goto :change)

:: more code here

exit

:change 
Powershell -command "Write-Host 'this is yellow becoz errorlevel was 1' -ForegroundColor Yellow"

@pause
```

> ^^Above code is just a example code and does not work, modify it
> according to your need for it to work^^

NOTE: This script will take about 2 seconds of a delay before it outputs the word (in my case), as it has to call Powershell and wait for response.

Hope this helps! ❤️

Comment: This writes new text in a different color, not change the color of existing colored text. The console only has 16 colors total and I'm looking to change one of them during runtime. Not simply select an existing color to use. Sorry if I didn't explain this well.